# How to select element inside Angular 1.5 component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

For [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component), I can no longer refer to `Elem` or `Attr` like I used to in its father -- directive, by taking them as arguments inside `link` or `post`.

What is the best way to select element like I used to in directive? Did it change the way how it should be done?

Why is it not documented in the component document for the Angular 1.5x?

Comment: You can refer to it the same way you do it in a traditional directive's controller. But if need to access the element, then `component` might not be the best choice in the first place. `directive` still has its place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the same thing inside component controller by injecting `$element` dependency. But on controller load `$element` is not compiled DOM.

For such case you could use Angular 1.5 component life cycle, like there we have [**`$postLink()`**](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2016/03/29/exploring-angular-1.5-lifecycle-hooks.html#postlink) which will work as same as like `postLink`/`link` function of Angular 1 directive.

For accessing attribute you inject `$attrs` service inside controller.

**Component**

```
myMod.component('myComponent', {
  template: '<h1>Home</h1>',
  controller: function($element) {
    this.test = 'hello world';
    this.$postLink = function(){
      //here you have compiled DOM
      //you can play with element here.
      console.log("Post LInk DOM", $element);
    }
    console.log("Initial DOM", $element);
  }
});
```